# Samba file server serves 1G+10G, how to handle a client that's also connected to both 1G+10G but should only use 10G for accessing server's shares?

Tags: networking, routing, network-shares, lan, samba

I have a file server running samba 4.5 on FreeBSD 11 and a few networked PCs, all on a simple unmanaged 1Gb LAN. The PCs include a workstation with a dedicated 10GbE optical link to the file server because it handles very large files. All LAN devices are all on the same workgroup, called "WORKGROUP", samba uses a device name "SERVER" and the workstation uses a device name "WS1". There's no local DNS/AD/WINS in use, and the samba daemon also acts as the workgroup's master browser (with WS1 as backup when I get that far).

[image]

The problem is that the workstation and file server are always connecting via their 1Gb connection and ignoring the 10G connection, and I want them to preferentially use the 10G connection if it exists and ignore the 1Gb connection if so. I can force samba over 10G by using \192.168.100.1 from the workstation (and it then works) but that's hardly ideal.

I'm concerned that if I randomly guess at solutions, I'll just cause worse problems elsewhere, perhaps because all other PCs can only "see" the server on the 1Gb LAN, so the server needs to "see" WS1 at a different IP from that "seen" by PC1-PC3 (how does it do that?), or else because WS1 or SERVER would need multiple names to be "seen" as multiple machines on 1Gb and 10GbE (how?), or because I need to create separate shares for SERVER_10G and SERVER_1G (duplicates work and will be a pain to be sure they're otherwise identical).

Because I'm not sure how to resolve this, I haven't tried to mess around yet in case I make it worse.

How do I configure this situation?

Comment: Network route metrics?

Comment: @ClassStacker - Interesting solution - to flesh it out a bit, you would need to add a gateway to 192.168.0.9 netmask 255.255.255.255 via 192.168.100.1 on 192.168.100.2 and similarly 192.168.0.8 netmask 255.255.255.255 via 192.168.100.2 on 192.168.100.1

Comment: Why not to get 10Gb switch with couple 10Gb ports and rest with 1Gb ports. You can find on ebay cisco 2x10Gb + 24x1Gb under 100 bucks. Plug server and WS1 to 10Gb ports and PC1-3 to 1Gb ports. You will get even more benefit when PC1-3 simultaneously accessing server - all of them  would get maximum speed.

Comment: @ClassStacker  - I like the idea (in principle); @davidgo - metrics aren't the same as a routing table (although both are possible solutions??). `man routed` is poor at explaining exactly how you specify that one route is more "costly" than another, for routing purposes. Do I need to add both a static route and a 'cost' (metric) to the 1Gb route, then? If so, how? (I'd like to make 192.168.0.x inherently more 'costly' than 22.168.100.x for all routes and devices if possible, so 10G will always be chosen preferentially across the entire LAN, if there's a way to do it?)

Comment: @Stilez Is `man 8 route` of any help? It's true that metrics are not _the_ routing table, but they're still _part of_ the routing table.

Comment: It looked promising (a bit more detail) but really not much, unfortunately it isn't of any help...